# Implementing PreferredSizeWidget For Use As Appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar, flutter-widget

I am trying to build a component that can be used to identify two columns in a listview. I wish to be able to implement this title bar as the appbar in a Scaffold such that I can implement the ListView in the body part of the Scaffold. I want to do this because I want to use this pattern multiple times throughout my app and do not wish to implement a crude title bar each time I do so.

Because all that is required for an AppBar component is the implementation of PreferredSizeWidget, I thought this should be pretty straightforward:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListTitleBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {

  final String _left;
  final String _right;

  ListTitleBar(this._left, this._right);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new ListTitleBarState(_left, _right);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize {
    new Size.fromHeight(20.0);
  }

}

class ListTitleBarState extends State<ListTitleBar> {

  String _leftTitle;
  String _rightTitle;

  ListTitleBarState(this._leftTitle, this._rightTitle);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return new Container(

  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.redAccent,
    border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black),
  ),

  child: new Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[

      ///Left Column Title
      new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Text(_leftTitle,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 18.0
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),

      ///Right Column Title
      new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Text(_rightTitle,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 18.0
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),

    ],
  ),
);

}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
}

 @override
 void dispose() {
   super.dispose();
 }

}
```

My question is about what else is needed to successfully implement PreferredSizeWidget or to accomplish my goal. Right now I am getting the following stack trace which seems to indicate that I am neglecting a few aspects of the implementation:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 9130): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Scaffold(dirty, state:
>   I/flutter ( 9130): ScaffoldState#7c75d(tickers: tracking 1 ticker)):
>   I/flutter ( 9130): The getter 'height' was called on null.
>   I/flutter ( 9130): Receiver: null
>   I/flutter ( 9130): Tried calling: height
>   I/flutter ( 9130): 
>   I/flutter ( 9130): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:46:5)
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #1      ScaffoldState.build (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1447:57)
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3713:27)
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3625:15)
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:11)
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
>   I/flutter ( 9130): #10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)

Comment: Basically u wat to create a component to have a Title and a list is that what you mean to say?

Comment: No I would like to create a component that I can assign to the appBar field in the Scaffold Widget. I would implement the ListView in the body field of the Scaffold.

Answer (score 25):

I think you forgot the `return` statement in your `preferredSize`. Should be like so:

`Size get preferredSize {
  return new Size.fromHeight(20.0);
}`

Comment: Or write it as:
```@override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(20.0);```

Arrow syntax doesn't require a `return` statement.

Comment: Or simply: `@override    final Size preferredSize;` (just override the field directly, this is how `PreferredSizeWidget` does it)